# Move an existing cell from an existing row into a new row using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to move a cell in a table to a new row. The table just contains one row with four cells. The third one is the one I need. The cell has to be removed from the existing row so only the new one contains it.

This is my markup:

```
<table class="sbtable">
<tbody>
<tr class="sbrow">
<td class="first">Blah</td>
<td class="second">Blah</td>
<td class="third">Blah</td>
<td class="last">Blah</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
function formatSearchBox() {
$(".sbtable").each(function () {
    var table = $(this);
    var firstRow = $(table).find("tr:first");
    var cell = $(firstRow).find("td").eq(2);
    var newRow = "<tr></tr>";
    $(newRow).append($(cell));
    console.log(newRow);
    $(newRow).append("<td></td><td></td><td></td>");
    $(firstRow).after($(newRow));
});
}
```

My problem is that the script only inserts a blank `<tr></tr>` and I have absolutely no idea why. I need the html like this:

```
<table class="sbtable">
<tbody>
<tr class="sbrow">
<td class="first">Blah</td>
<td class="second">Blah</td>
<td class="last">Blah</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="third">Blah</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: close the <tr> like </tr>

Comment: and it should be `$(".sbtable")` in your js code

Comment: I have changed selectors to make it easier to read and there is no problem there. Only with inserting the cell into a new row. And what do you mean by closing <tr> like </tr>?

Comment: This is my first time coding JQuery so maybe I wrote the new selectors wrong.

Comment: Looks like you're appending again three blank columns.$(newRow).append("<td></td><td></td><td></td>"); Try adding only two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector was wrong as explained in comments above but the main problem was you that you have to update newRow var as you can see below:

`$(newRow).append($(cell));`

you need

`newRow = $(newRow).append($(cell));`

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/dc6fM/3/

```
$(".sbtable").each(function () {
    var table = $(this);
    var firstRow = $(table).find("tr:first");
    var cell = $(firstRow).find("td:eq(2)");
    var newRow = "<tr></tr>";
    newRow= $(newRow).append(cell);
    newRow.append("<td></td><td></td>");
    $(firstRow).after(newRow);
});
```

Or try shorter version if you prefer: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/dc6fM/2/

```
$(".sbtable").each(function () {
    var $table = $(this);
    var $cell = $table.find("tr:first td:eq(2)");
    $table.append($("<tr>").append($cell,"<td></td><td></td>"))        
});
```

Or even shorter: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/dc6fM/5/

Comment: Thanks! This works, I guess I used $() the wrong way.

Comment: `newRow` is already a jQuery object on the second line after defined, so you don't need to pass it in `$(...)`, I hate such a messy code, is not logic at all and uncessarily redundant.

Comment: @filoxo done. King King, I fixed the issues. The code can be written in million different ways each with its own benefits. I suggested the shorter version which I think covers your point.

Comment: @AamirAfridi I don't think the original version has any benefit here, again the function `$()` will have to turn the already jQuery object into another jQuery object, not sure what it has to do but it's obviously unnecessary.

Comment: @KingKing I understand what you say and completely agrees with you. I just wanted to fix the basic issue the questioner was having.

Answer (score 2):

You have created 3 separate rows:

```
var newRow = "<tr></tr>";
$(newRow).append($(cell)); // new row created and cell appended to it
$(newRow).append("<td></td><td></td><td></td>");  // a different new row created, 3 cells appended
$(firstRow).after($(newRow)); // yet another row created, empty and appended
```

Each time you are calling `$(newRow)` you create another brand new row.

Instead, save the row to the variable:

```
var $newRow = $("<tr></tr>");
$newRow.append($(cell)); 
$newRow.append("<td></td><td></td><td></td>");  
$(firstRow).after($newRow);
```

Comment: Also, unrelated to your issue, so I won't add it to the answer, but you are double-wrapping all of your jquery objects.  For instance, `firstRow` is already a jquery object, don't use `$(firstRow).find` just use `firstRow.find`.

Answer (score 1):

your newRow variable is just a string and using the jquery .append method is not working for you.  newRow needs to be a jquery object to be worked on.

```
var newRow = $("<td></td>");
newRow.append("<td></td><td></td><td></td>");
```

Notice also in the 2nd line, I am not using $(newRow) as the variable already refers to the Jquery object. I see you are doing that when calling $(table) and $(firstRow).

Comment: Care to explain why? Doesn't that code create a new <td> DOM element (that can then be inserted into the tree)?

Comment: He don't want to create a new TD. He wants to move third cell from first row to a new row